# complex manifolds are complex analytic spaces

Tags: manifolds, complex-geometry

Are complex manifolds complex analytic spaces? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analytic_space

What does it mean that there can be singularities in a complex analytic space but not on a complex manifold?

Comment: We can regard a complex manifold as a generalization of smooth surface.

Comment: Not sure what means an open subset of the zero locus of finitely many holomorphic functions. For example $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x}-y$ what are the open subsets of $\{ (x,-1/x), x \in \mathbb{C}^* \}$ ? And how do you get some singularities this way ?

Comment: open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are not necessarily analytic subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ right?

Answer (score 2):

Complex manifolds are indeed complex analytic spaces. As in the wikipedia link you've attached, complex analytic spaces is the generalization of complex manifolds. Complex manifolds are locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$, while complex analytic spaces are locally isomorphic to zero sets of holomorphic functions.

Comment: Small caveat: Complex manifolds look locally like a ball $B_1(0) \subset \mathbb C^n$, which is not biholomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$.

Answer (score -1):

A complex manifold is *by definition* smooth. It looks locally like $\mathbb C^n$ with smoothly differentiable transition functions.

A complex analytic space however, is more general. It looks locally like the zero set of finitely many polynomials.

**Example:** The zero set $V$ of $f=x^3-y^2$ in $\mathbb C^2$ is a cusp. Topologically, it looks like a pinched sphere with one point removed.

One can also consider the closure of $V$ in $\mathbb C \mathbb P^2$, which is defined by the zero set of the homogeneous polynomial $\overline f = x^3-y^2z$. This looks topologically like a pinched sphere (without any points removed).

It is obtained by glueing the spaces defined by the dehomogenizations $f_1 = x^3-y^2$, $f_2=x^3-z$ and $f_3=1-y^2z$.

Comment: There are, of course, complex analytic spaces that are not locally cut out by polynomial equations (these are the algebraic varieties). Complex analytic spaces are, more generally, locally cut out by analytic functions. There is only Chow's theorem that says that closed analytic subvarieties in projective space are in fact algebraic. In the non-projective case. most  analytic spaces will be non-algebraic